# redireccionamiento en php

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un formulario de registro y en la comprobación de los datos pregunto si el mail o el usuario no están registrados funciona todo bien el problema es que una vez que sale el error pongo ok y se redirecciona a **registro.php** y yo quiero que se quede en **index.php**

dejo el codigo donde deberia estar el problema

```
    if ((mysqli_num_rows($existente)>0) or ($clave != $claverep)){
   echo "<script>alert(\"Error en el registro\")</script>";
  "<script> window.location.replace=../index.php'</script>";
    }
```

Comment: Prueba a poner `echo "<script> window.location[...]` Ahora mismo no está imprimiendo esa parte del script.

Comment: llega a imprimir, pero donde pongo ok se va a registro.php y yo quiero que quede en index.php

Answer (score 0):

Te falta una comilla en la linea donde haces el replace al location:

```
if ((mysqli_num_rows($existente)>0) or ($clave != $claverep)){
  echo "<script>alert(\"Error en el registro\")</script>";
 echo "<script> window.location.replace('../index.php'); </script>";
   }
```

Comment: no es eso igual sigue redireccionando a registro.php

Comment: Y si pruebas cambiando el replace por href ?

Comment: Había pasado algo por alto y es que `replace()` es un método por lo cual teníamos la sintaxis equivocada.

Comment: probe con href sacando el replace, en realidad probe primero sin el replace y no le encuentro la forma

Comment: @Houth algo más que pasamos por alto fue el echo de la línea del location

Comment: tampoco funciona asi jaja aun que ahora me manda a la pagina del xampp y no a registro.php

Comment: Y la ruta '../index.php' es correcta? o debería de ser 'index.php' ?

Answer (score 0):

ya lo solucione faltaba un echo en el segundo script y tenia un . de mas en el ./index.php

```
if ((mysqli_num_rows($existente)>0) or ($clave != $claverep)){
   echo "<script>alert(\"Error en el registro\")</script>";
  echo"<script> window.location=('./index.php')</script>";
    }
```